# Saving & Referencing different Schema Types in MongoDB (e.g. for a CMS with Building Blocks)

Tags: database, database-design, nosql, mongodb, document-databases

Say I wanted to build my own CMS system and store data in MongoDB. I would like to have a Collection called `BlogArticle`. Each article can have a different structure, but will be put together by the same building blocks.

So for example, `Blog Article No. 1` might look like this:

```
1. Title: "2 Great Videos of Cats"
2. Video-Component
3. Text-Component
4. Video-Component
5. Text-Component
```

But `Blog Article No. 2` would look like this:

```
1. Title: "2 Great Videos of Cats"
2. Text-Component
```

... and so on. I am wondering how I would set something like this up in MongoDB? Since (normally) a collection only holds objects of the same type. I could of course just store id's, but even those, (as far as I know), would always be looked up in one single collection of the same type?

How would I go about something like this? How can I use MongoDB to be flexible in cases like these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a fairly narrow concept of “object” or “document”. This is not needed for a document database. The documents can be deeply nested, and need not have the exact same shape.

I'd expect that you would represent your blog posts as documents like these:

```json
{
  "title": "2 Great Videos of Cats",
  "content": [
    { "type": "Video", ... },
    { "type": "Text", ... },
    { "type": "Video", ... },
    { "type": "Text", ... }
  ]
}
```

So the blocks probably wouldn't be linked to a different collection, but would be embedded directly into the post's document. No lookups needed. Of course, you *could* have a block collection. The documents in this collection could have different fields, depending on their type.

Comment: this is a really great answer. But what if my building blocks  (`Video`, `Text`) are really really large (I know that in this particular example they likely won't be)? Would I then still want to store them in an array inside the parent?

Comment: @antonwilhelm Your MongoDB documents can be up to 16MB large, which is more than enough for a page in the CMS. But media and resources should be stored externally, e.g. as plain files or with a S3 style object storage. The external media files can then be referenced from your Video block by an URL.

Comment: I didn't mean to ask it like that. I just meant, what about a scenario, where I want to store very large building blocks (say it's not a blog but something else)? Also, won't storing them all in one object slow things down if I wanted to have an overview page of all my blog posts? Even if I just display the title, my database would have to go through each document, which will be a much heavier task if I were to store a very large array in each document (I agree that for a simple blog post this would not be the case).

Comment: @antonwilhelm Yes, that could become a problem. You could write queries that only return the relevant parts of the document (MongoDB calls this projections). You could have a separate collection for post summaries. Personally, if I were to design such a system, I'd probably avoid MongoDB and use Postgres instead which supports a mix of relational data (e.g. posts have a title column) and NoSQL-style documents (e.g. a content column containing JSON).

Answer (score 1):

It's called [Polymorphic pattern](https://developer.mongodb.com/how-to/polymorphic-pattern/). I'll speak in terms of OOP because that's what I have experience with, plus the name itself pushes in that direction.

MongoDB knows documents, not your type, so it can't tell you what it's storing. So yes, generally you want documents of the same type in a collection, so that you can keep track of *what* you write *where*, and this kind of "[type erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure)" isn't a problem.

But what is a type? An abstract class or an interface *are* types!

So, as long as you have a base abstract class `AbstractBuildingBlock`, you can have an implementation for each of the content types. Eg: `TextBuildingBlock` would need to store some text and formatting information, `VideoBuildingBlock` the URL to the stream, content type and subtitles... etc.

I suppose you could even have a collection of `Object`, if you really want to put anything in the collection. MongoDB wouldn't mind...

The polymorphic pattern is supported by [MongoDB Java Driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.2/bson/pojos/) by adding a **type discriminator** - nothing more than a field in the document that says "this is a Video", like the one in @amon's answer - so that the codec can instantiate the right `AbstractBuildingBlock` implementation. This is supported at the collection level, but also in arrays nested deep into the document and, I suppose, even on single document fields.

```
// polymorphic pattern at the collection level
collection: [
    { _id: 1, type: "video", url: "www.videos.com/xxx", ... },
    { _id: 2, type: "text", content: "Lorem ipsum", ... },
    ...
]
```

Is this supported also in non-OOP languages? Well, I'm not a computer scientist, but since basically [polymorphism is the solution to having switch over types all over the place](https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html), you could just switch over the discriminator.

The funny thing about this approach is that it will almost feel like *storing the behaviour* of objects. If you have an `animals` collection, you can just retrieve them and call `AbstractAnimal.speak()` on them, and Pluto the pup will woof and Donald the duck will quack. However you're not actually storing the behaviour: that stays in the code, unless you're parameterising/versioning it and storing the parameters/version.

This pattern and the above fact might make you think: "*Why don't I just store my domain entities? The persistence layer will be so thin, I'll be so fast!*". Well, for a simple CRUD prototype application that might be true. But as tempting as it is, that will likely be a bad decision because **your domain and your storage will have different needs and will need different models**: trying to solve both problems at once will lead to a solution that is bad for either or even both.

One last note: the decision of storing the building blocks inside the "page" document as @amon proposes, or having references to a proper "building blocks" collection, is another *huge* topic (see [5](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-relationships/) and [6](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mongodb-applied-design/9781449340056/ch01.html)).